# In bash for loop error in conditional checking

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have a for loop to check list of nodes that I have in file whether they are alive:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpnodes=$(cat $1)
#declare -a nodes
nodes=()
for node in $tmpnodes
do
        result=$(ping -q -c 1 -W 2 $node >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)
        echo "Result: $result, on node $node"
        if [ $result -eq 0 ] ; then
                nodes+=("$node")
                #nodes=(${nodes[@]} "$node")
        fi
done

echo "pingable nodes:"
for node in $nodes
do
        echo "$node"
done
```

( I have also tried the version with `declare`)

Although I have more pingable nodes I always get this output :

```
$  ./script.sh nodes
Result: 1, on node clab148node11
Result: 1, on node clab148node12
Result: 0, on node clab148node15
Result: 0, on node clab148node16
Result: 0, on node clab148node17
Result: 0, on node clab148node18
pingable nodes:
clab148node15
```

Comment: And the question is?...

Comment: @Floris ok now I see... I had to do `${nodes[@]}` to print all nodes

Comment: You might find it helpful to echo $nodes every iteration of your first loop...

Comment: Solved your own problem!

Comment: You're sure that those nodes, which you say you expect to be pingable, are pingable on the first try, within two milliseconds (`-c 1 -W 2`)?

Comment: @Patryk: it's OK to add an answer for your own question, to make it easier for others to see if they find this question while researching their own problem.

Comment: @minopret `-W` is timeout in seconds not miliseconds. I will add my answer to this in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
for node in $nodes
do
        echo "$node"
done
```

which was indeed printing the very first element of the array each time I did this :

```
echo ${nodes[@]}
```